# How to figure out if _id field in MongDB was generate by mongo or passed by user during insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoid

I have an app where we pass _id to mongodb during insert instead of using the build in _id generation logic. Now in my DB I see lots of document with _id:Object('')

I need to find count of all the documents who's Id were generated by MONGO, anyone knows how??

Comment: A user-generated ObjectId will look the same as an internally generated ObjectId. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Are you passing _id as ObjectId from your application? If not it can be identified. Else you have to use a new field in the document which is added from your application to distinguish the documents

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MongoDB [`$type` query operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/).

```
db.collection.count({ _id: { $type: "objectId" } })
```